# ODBC Driver issue for CSV files

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm using this code in VBA (SQL) to connect to an external Excel file and copy some data.

It is working for XLS and XLSX file, But i need to adapt it for **CSV**:

````
Sub Conect()

'conection string
str_Conexao = _
"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" & _
"DSN=TESTE_SQL;DBQ=C:\Dropbox\Vol\Daily\Sheet.xlsx" ";" _
& "ReadOnly=0;DefaultDir=C:\Dropbox\Vol\Daily\";" _
& "DriverId=1046;FIL=excel 12.0;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;"

'set DODB
Set ado_Conexao = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'open conection
ado_Conexao.Open str_Conexao

End Sub ```
````

Comment: Try some of these connection strings https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-text-odbc-driver/ FYI, CSV is just a text file

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I encourage you to paste your final solution as an answer then accept it. That anyone with the same issue who finds this answer will have a solution